# Solve NC + BN =F

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I asked this in the computer section; someone suggested asking in the maths section:
Is there a simple way to solve the following matrix equation for N:

NC + BN = F

The matrices B, C, and F are known.

Thank you for any help.

o.

Comment: What's your way?

Comment: @AtulGangwar:Sorry, I have no idea how to solve it rigorously. I can make a guess for N (call it N0) then solve B*N = (F-N0*C) to get N=N1 and continue iterating. I don't know if it will converge, though. Is there a cleaner/rigorous way?

Answer (score 0):

Think of $N,F$ as long vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ instead of matrices.
That is, think of $[N]_{ij}$ as the $i+(j-1)n$ entry of a long vector.

Then you have $[NC+BN]_{ij} = [NC]_{ij}  + [BN]_{ij} = \sum_k [N]_{ik} [C]_{kj}+ \sum_k [B]_{ik} [N]_{kj} = [F]_{ij}$. This gives rise to a big square matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n^2}$, which you then solve for $N$.

Comment: OK, thank you. I worry that the big square matrix quickly gets out of hand (too large). Thank you very much

Comment: Well, you are solving a system of $n^2$ unknowns. Alternatively, if you know something about the structure of $B,C$, there may be other ways.